# Jquery doesn't find Controller in MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I trying to use jQuery 3.1 in my application, for test I wrote the next method in Controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public string GetNotice()
 {
    return "Hello world!";
 }
```

and JS code in my HomePage.html:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#saveNotice").button().click(function () {
            $.get('/Controllers/NoticeController/GetNotice', function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });

        });
```

And I always have error:

> ET http://localhost:58421/Controllers/NoticeController/GetNotice 404
>   (Not Found)

Maybe somebody to know how I can resolve it ?

The HomePage.html locale in project folder.

Comment: just remove the `\Controllers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the default routing schema that's used when you create a new MVC project, then you shouldn't add the `/controllers/` folder, and you should also remove the `controller` suffix from the name of the target controller. Try this:

```
$("#saveNotice").button().click(function () {
    $.get('/Notice/GetNotice', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

If it's possible to use Razor in your JS code then you can make the route dynamic by using `@Url.Action`:

```
$("#saveNotice").button().click(function () {
    $.get('@Url.Action("GetNotice", "Notice")', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you don't specify "Controllers" in your url. By default, your routing config will ignore the "Controllers" path. MVC will also ignore the "Controller" suffix. But double check your routing config to be sure.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#saveNotice").button().click(function () {
            $.get('/Notice/GetNotice', function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });

        });
```